# Make hyphens appear in an acronym when used as an adjective

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms

I have an acronym defined as `\acro{BSM}[BSM]{Beyond Standard Model}` which appears the first time as an adjective.
I would therefore like it to be hyphenated, so that instead of having:

`Beyond Standard Model (BSM) Physics`

it would appear as:

`Beyond-Standard-Model (BSM) Physics`

Is there a way to force this behaviour?

Comment: obviously latex can not tell an adjective automatically, can't you simply use hyphens in the defintion of the acronym?

Comment: Not really, given that it is not only used as an adjective. I was hoping for some option like \acadj that automatically hyphenizes all the words